# TypeError: doc.fromHTML is not a function

Tags: javascript, wordpress, printing, jspdf

So i'm running this code to print sections on a page using jsPDF but he keeps returning

> TypeError: doc.fromHTML is not a function

```
function printPDF(object){
    var section_id = jQuery(object).parent().find('p').text().substr(0,3).replace('.','_');
    if(!jQuery('#contentsection'+section_id).length){
        jQuery(object).parent().parent().parent().before('<div id="contentsection'+section_id+'">'+'</div>');
    }
    var title_block = jQuery(object).parent().parent().parent();
    var text_under_title = jQuery(object).parent().parent().parent().next();
    jQuery('#contentsection'+section_id).append(title_block);
    jQuery('#contentsection'+section_id).append(text_under_title);

    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    }; 

    jQuery('.print-to-pdf').click(function () {
        doc.fromHTML(jQuery('#contentsection'+section_id).html(), 15, 15, {
            'width': 170,
           // 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });
        doc.save('test-file.pdf');
    });

}
```

Someone that knows what happens or knows what  i'm doing wrong, i dont know what these 'elementHandlers' are too.

Comment: I don't see any printPDF() call... The "doc" object is defined there. And, it seems like the printPDF function is missing an end bracket ( } )... From what you show here.

Comment: The printPDF is called in an onclick like this  function appendPdf($){
 $('.heading').append('<div onclick = "printPDF(this)" class="print-to-pdf"></div>');
}

Comment: I'm having hard time to recreate the problem... Can you post a sample of your HTML ?

Comment: I would need it... Because there is a parent hierarchy and a p id that I "faked" in my local test. The PDF is created... Twice on second click, strangely.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you import jspdf.js instead of jspdf.debug.js. The latter doesn't have the fromHTML() function so it throws error.

Include proper libraries.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```

Make sure jspdf.js is not present in references.